# how to decode QUrlnfo.name()?

Tags: qt, ftp, locale, urlencode

I received the following QUrlInfo string from QFtp::listInfo(QUrlInfo) and the correct URL fragment is actually set to **©®§µ** here in a test.

But QUrlInfo.name() returns a String containing **Â©Â®Â§Âµ**. I realize I must encode it somehow, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
QString::fromUtf8(info.name().toAscii());
```

Comment: I've also found out ftp->cd(dirName.toUtf8()) is the opposite for those things